# Searching char arrays to see if the char matches

Tags: java

I have two char arrays that takes two strings as the input. If the char on either side has the matching char, for example after translating the char Arrays into string char A and B both have at least one H or R, then it will return true. If not then return false.

```
>char[] A = foo(A).toCharArray();
>
>char[] B = foo(B).toCharArray();
>
>System.out.println("String "+A+": "+Arrays.toString(A));
>
>System.out.println("String "+B+": "+Arrays.toString(B));

>String A: [H,  , R,  ]
>
>String B: [R,  , R, R]
>>This will return true

>String A: [ , H,  , R]
>
>String B: [H, H,  , H]
>>This will return true

>String A: [H,  , H,  ]
>
>String B: [R,  , R,  ]
>>This will return false
```

I'm confused how to make such rule?

Comment: Is the matching char given as an input? or is it any char from the first array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Set` here which will give the result in one iteration. Using `java.util.TreeSet` further reduce the execution time as it eliminates duplicates

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] A = "HR".toCharArray();
    char[] B = "RRR".toCharArray();

    Set<Character> set = new TreeSet<>();
    boolean flag = false;
    for(char c : A) {
        set.add(c);
    }
    for(char c : B) {
        if(set.contains(c)) {
            System.out.println(true);
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag) {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That you can do is use a For to iterate in the matriz and verify if the current item is 'R' or 'H'.

```html
boolean returnedValue = false;

for(int i = 0; i< B.length; i++){
  char currentItem = B[i];
  if(currentItem == 'R' || currentItem == 'H'){
    returnedValue = true;
 }
}

return returnedValue;
```

Comment: Where's the first array? You are only checking if 'H' or 'R' are in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first loop to take each element from the first array.

Use the second loop to check the first element inside the second array.

Check if the current value in the first array is equal to H or R.

If it is, check if it's in the second array and return true.

```
public static boolean check() {
        String s1 = "ABHEEF", s2 = "RDDFVW";
        char[] arr1 = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] arr2 = s2.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if(arr1[i] == 'H' || arr1[i] == 'R') {
                    if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])
                        return true;
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its simple all you have to do is to add a nested loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < B.length; j++){
             if(if B[j] ==A [i]){
                  return true
             }
      }
}

        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 1.8 you could do something like following:

```
//@Momir Sarac
String text1 = "b9H ello";
String text2 ="avn1c fk";
// 32 is for empty space character here, you could do i != ' ' and it would be the same
//turn text1 into intstream each int corresponding to it's char value
//filter empty space ints
//get only distinct out of them
//take a look for any match if some int is contained within text2
boolean result = text1.chars().filter(i->i != 32).distinct().anyMatch(character->text2.contains(String.valueOf(character)) || text2.lastIndexOf(character) != -1);
//print it on screen
System.out.printf("Two texts %s same letter(s).", result ? "have" : "don't have");
```